# Having trouble with Google script authorizations, need help remotely updating many (dozens of) Google Forms

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, triggers, authorization, google-forms

I'm setting up an event to encourage people to stay physically active.  Once someone registers, they are sent a copy of a Google Form/Sheet template that they will use to create their team.  Each member of the team will enter their name, select the activity that they performed and record how long they performed it.  The log Form should automatically update to list these names and activities so that the users can select from this list later rather than enter them again.  The linked Response spreadsheet has charts comparing the team members activities to each other.  I have a 'master' spreadsheet that imports the data from all of the team's response sheets and compares and displays them (on Google Slides) for the participants to view.

The problem that I'm having is that I would like to be able to programmatically authorize the Log Form auto update so that I don't need to do it manually every time a new Log Form is generated.

Things tried:

1) Form ranger - the Form ranger configuration can be setup in the form template, but is lost once the template is copied, requiring me to reconfigure (and authorize) the Form Ranger each new form as it's generated.

2) Use Google script to update the form with an onFormSubmit trigger.  Process is working but I need to manually setup the onFormSubmit trigger, the first time, in each new Form/Spreadsheet in order for it to continue automatically afterward.

3) Updated the manifest file to include: "oauthScopes": ["https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets.currentonly"]  When I tried this, the script generated an error indicating 'You do not have permission to call SpreadsheetApp.openById'.  It began working again after removing the '.currentonly' but still required me to manual authorize it for each new Form/SS.

4) Added
/**
 * @OnlyCurrentDoc
 */
to the script.  This added several seconds to the script runtime but, other than that, I didn't notice any change.  Still required me to manually authorize.

5) I've tried using simple triggers (onOpen and onEdit) to detect changes in the Form's linked Response sheet, but found that these triggers are not activated with the form's automated sending of data to the spreadsheet but rather when the USER manually performs the operations on the spreadsheet.  So still no automated updating.

Do you have any other ideas?  I appreciate any assistance that you can provide.

Thanks,
David

Comment: Not quite sure either I understand you correctly. You create a separate form for each team and want  each of those forms to be edited automatically once a user filled them out? You are the owner of all the forms and spreadsheets? It would be helpful if you could clarify, maybe provide a template of the form and your modification script. Until then: 1. onOpen and onEdit will not work for formSubmit - only `onFormSubmit` trigger will. 2. You can can bind the script and the `onFormSubmit` trigger to the form instead of the spreadsheet - if this helps.

Comment: Yes, each team receives their own form that they use to log their workout and I am the owner of the forms and their linked spreadsheets.  I'd like the log form's questions to update so that the user's name and activities are displayed in a list that the user can select from the next time that they have an activity to log.  How will putting the form update script and onFormSubmit trigger in the form help?  Will that remove the need for me to authorize the onFormSubmit?

Comment: If you have something run on a trigger, you will need to authorize it only once, the very first time, for the subsequent times the script will be fired automatically by a trigger. But your workflow is not quite clear to me. Can you provide your script that modifies the form? At what point do you want this modification to take place? And shall it happen only once?